# JButton in IDE will click, but not in the .jar file

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, thread-sleep

In the Netbeans IDE, I wrote a program that creates a JButton in a JFrame. The JButton is visible, and it is clickable, but when the JButton is clicked, sometimes the program will not detect it. The cases where this happens is **always** when I run it from the .jar file Netbeans compiles for you automatically. My code that waits for the JButton to be clicked is as follows:

```
while(!(btn.getModel().isPressed())){ //btn is the JButton here
}
```

This works in the Netbeans, when I run it inside the IDE, but it never detects when the JButton is clicked when the program is run with the .jar file. One thing that I did try is to add a delay in the loop. At first I thought that the loop was looping too fast too detect a single click, so I added a delay of 1 millisecond in between:

```
while(!(btn.getModel().isPressed())){
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        '//Exception handling
    }
}
```

This also works in the IDE, but it still does not work in the .jar file. Is there a problem with `btn.getModel().isPressed()`? If there is a problem, what is a good alternative to `btn.getModel().isPressed()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using an ActionListener.

To add an ActionListener to your button, use this:
    `btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ });`
Now that you've done that, inside of the ActionListener, put this method:
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){ }`
Now that you've done that, insert the `Thread.sleep(1)` into the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: I will try that, but could you explain why it is only clicking in my IDE? That is still very confusing to me.